# Call Procedure / Function JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, procedure

Hey guys I have a procedure in postgres SQL and I'm trying call it using jpa hibernate, but I'm getting error.

```
    select * from myprocedure(2016, 3, 0, 0,0)
AS f(descricao varchar, itens integer, quantidade bigint, valor numeric)
```

and here what im trying do in java.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(" SELECT * ");
            sb.append(" FROM myprocedure( ");
            sb.append(" :ano , ");
            if (Util.isNotNull(mes)) {
                sb.append(":mes , ");
            }
            sb.append(" :codNre , ");
            sb.append(" :codMun , ");
            sb.append(" 0) ");
            sb.append(" AS f(descricao varchar, itens integer, quantidade bigint, valor numeric) ");

            TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createQuery(sb.toString(), Tuple.class);

            query.setParameter("ano", ano);
            if (Util.isNotNull(mes)) {
                query.setParameter("mes", mes);
            }
            query.setParameter("codNre", codNre);
            query.setParameter("codMun", codMun);

            List<ResumoDistribuicaoMerendaDTO> listaRetorno = new ArrayList<ResumoDistribuicaoMerendaDTO>();

            List<Tuple> results = query.getResultList();
            for (Tuple result : results) {
                ResumoDistribuicaoMerendaDTO resumoMerenda = new ResumoDistribuicaoMerendaDTO();
                resumoMerenda.setDescricaoAlimento(result.get(0).toString());
                resumoMerenda.setItens(Integer.valueOf(result.get(1).toString()));
                resumoMerenda
                        .setQuantidade(result.get(2) == null ? new Long(0) : Long.parseLong(result.get(2).toString()));
                resumoMerenda.setValor(result.get(3) == null ? new BigDecimal(0)
                        : BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(result.get(3).toString())));

                listaRetorno.add(resumoMerenda);
            }
```

and the exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 9 [ SELECT *  FROM myprocedure(  :ano , :mes ,  :codNre ,  :codMun ,  0)  AS f(descricao varchar, itens integer, quantidade bigint, valor numeric) ]

I already try replace the * for f but not working =\

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PostgreSQL's SQL in `createQuery()`. The `createQuery` command accepts only Java Persistence Query Language (JPQL) which will not know the `myprocedure` defined in your database.

You will either have to use `em.createNativeQuery(...)` for that (check documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql)) or use something like [this](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa/)